# Trigger to update age when inserted age < 0

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, insert, sql-update

I am trying to set age = 0 if the age is inserted as negative. I don't know what is wrong with the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER verify_age
BEFORE INSERT ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.age < 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE customers
SET age = 0
END;
```

Comment: Tip - never store *age* or any value that is mutable over time.

Comment: In real life applications, there are probably few values not mutable over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntactical error in your code is that it is missing a `;` before `END`, but even if you correct this it would not solve your problem.

You need a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement so that you update only the new row and not the whole table.
The condition in the `WHERE` clause will check for the `rowid` of the new row, but this `rowid` exists only *after* the row is inserted.
So, you must change the trigger to an `AFTER INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER verify_age AFTER INSERT ON customers
  WHEN NEW.age < 0
  BEGIN
    UPDATE customers
    SET age = 0
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
  END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9j0pcGuC).

Comment: The code you gave me worked but when should I use the "FOR EACH ROW"?

Comment: @TheRi From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#description: *"At this time SQLite supports only FOR EACH ROW triggers, not FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers. Hence explicitly specifying FOR EACH ROW is optional."*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER validate_age
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON customers
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.age < 0
    THEN
        :new.age := 0;
    END IF;
END;
```

or :

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_age 
       BEFORE INSERT ON customers
    BEGIN
       SELECT
          CASE
        WHEN NEW.age < 0 THEN
          NEW.age = 0
           END;
    END;
```

Comment: Hello. I got this when I used the first one:                                                   Parse error: near "IF": syntax error
  age BEFORE INSERT ON customers FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF :new.age < 0 THEN :new.ag
                                      error here ---^